# Node.js - MongoDB find().forEach() Not Pushing to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am currently able to run `.find().forEach(function(result))` and use `console.log` to see what was returned from my MongoDB server using `Node.js`. Yet when I attempt to do `array.push(result.name)` the array is not updated. Below is the script that I am using:

```
// Create temp array to store orders
var orderArray = [];
// Connect to Orders
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://10.254.17.115:27017/Orders', function(err, db) {
    // Handle errors
    assert.equal(null, err);

    var found = db.collection('Orders').find().forEach(function (result) {
        orderArray.push(result.OrderID);
        console.log(result.OrderID);
    });

    //socket.emit('GetOrders', orderArray);
});
// Return order array
console.log("Array used for debug " + orderArray);
```

I would assume that the script I used would work since the scope of orderArray[] is able to reach inside and outside the `.find()` function. Would anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: you have that equal sign after orderArray, assuming thats not really in the code?

Comment: `orderArray` is `[]` when you accessed it. `.find()` is **asynchronous** operation. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @JordanHendrix It's not really in the code, just a typo.

Comment: tushar comment is the right one